# rxjs auditTime only for same values

Tags: rxjs

I have a function which sends AJAX requests. I want to ignore the extra calls this function if they occur too often. I could do it using auditTime() operator:

```
const requestStream$ = new Subject<IRequestOptions>();

requestStream$
.pipe(
    auditTime(1000) // no more than 1 time in 1 second
)
.subscribe(requestOptions => {
    // send AJAX
});

requestStream$.next({
    url: 'http://example.com',
    method: 'post',
    headers: {}
});
```

The problem is that I need to ignore requests only with the same parameters:

```
requestStream$.next('site1');
requestStream$.next('site1'); // call after 500 msec (ignore)
requestStream$.next('site1'); // call after 500 msec (not ignore because it is 1000 msec from first request)
requestStream$.next('site2'); // call after 500 msec (must NOT ignore because there is different url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupBy` to group the incoming requests by some parameter. Then throttle each group separately.

```ts
import { throttleTime, mergeMap, groupBy } from 'rxjs/operators';

requestStream$
  .pipe(
    groupBy(request => request.url),
    mergeMap(group => group.pipe(throttleTime(1000)))
  )
```

I used `throttleTime` instead of `auditTime` because you won't get your described behaviour with `auditTime`. `auditTime` will initially wait 1 second and only then emit the last request within a 1 second time window whereas `throttleTime` will emit the first request immediately and then ignore further requests within a 1 second time window.